# Grunt - is it possible to watch custome module less files?

Tags: magento2, module, less, grunt

I figured out how to watch less files changes inside my custome theme folder using Grunt, but is there any way how to watch less files in custome module?

Let's assume module like so:

```
    app/code/Esencis/Nakup
```

For example, I would like to watch changes of file:

```
    app/code/Esencis/Nakup/view/frontend/web/css/mycss.css
```

Removing pub/static and var/generation files does work, however it is not much effective.